# Pulling google finance data with ISIN as an identifier

Tags: python, google-finance, google-finance-api

I would like to pull intraday data of any stocj in google finance just by asking for its ISIN number (not the google symbol). 
Is there is a way to do so using the python API googlefinance ?

Thanks

Comment: I can pull data from google inance with any symbol, but I need to do the same thing with an ISIN instead, I have tried by just putting the isininstead of the symbol put as expected it shows an error.